# Overlay Icons from Shell extension not working correctly

Tags: windows-11, shell-extensions

I have a Shell Extension which changes the overlay icons for folders and files in my app folder. It is created on my own. On Windows 10 it works as expected but on Windows 11 they are not shown/set. I don't know if this is a known issue, but I hope someone can help :)

And the limitation is no problem. My app is at the beginning of the list in the registry.

Comment: Overlay icons in Shell Namespace Extension work fine in Windows 11, I mean just like Windows 10 (still limited to 15 overlay icons for the whole system...). Or show some reproducing sample code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That is strange. In my case, it does not work. And I have no idea why. It is the same code as on Windows 10 but it does not work.

Comment: See for yourself: https://i.imgur.com/Cz3OpMk.png

Comment: I believe that you tell the truth, but it is really strange :) is it possible that you post your sample code? I will see if I can extract some sample code.

Comment: It's a product https://www.callback.com/cbfsshell/ with this sample https://github.com/callbacktechnologies/CBFSShell-Samples/tree/master/CBFSShell.Samples/ShellBoost.Samples.LocalFolder so it won't help you much as you won't see the native part of it.... You should post your code

Comment: @SimonMourier in your image I can see that there is an error icon as overlay icon. Should it be an error image? Because on another Windows 11 PC I can see badges for my project but they are all error badges. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: The error icon is the overlay icon https://github.com/callbacktechnologies/CBFSShell-Samples/tree/master/CBFSShell.Samples/ShellBoost.Samples.LocalFolder/Resources

Comment: And can you see the warningoverlay?

Comment: Yes, any overlay works.

Comment: In the end, I wrote everything new and it is working now. Thanks for your help.